# Use Apple Keyboard shortcuts on Windows

Tags: windows, mac, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

I have a PC and a Mac and I often switch between both of them. I am quite used to the Apple Keyboard (AZERTY French) shortcuts such as

- CMD + C/CMD + V for copy / paste
- Shift + Option + 5 / ° for square brackets
- and so on

I don't want to switch to Windows shortcut whenever I switch computers. Is there a way to emulate all Apple Keyboard shortcuts on my Windows?
I have downloaded Microsoft Keyboard Layout but I don't know how to use it. Any useful resources to do so?

Comment: Long-term, it's far better to get used to the difference, don't fight it.

Comment: Both MacOS and Windows allow you to load alternate keyboard drivers; you can minimize - _but likely not completely eliminate_ - the differences by ensuring that you have the same language/keyboard selection in both environments (in your case, the appropriate French layout).

Comment: How many many Windows shortcuts would like to break for this? You are going to lose too much functionality for this to be viable.

Comment: I don't know if I can fight it as I am likely going to code both on PC and Mac. But yeah, I guess I don't have much of a choice if there is no viable solution.

Answer (score 0):

look at this Apple article

Use your Apple Keyboard in Windows with Boot Camp

https://support.apple.com/en-sg/HT202676

Use Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator to find the key combinations for unique characters in the language and region your Apple keyboard is designed to support:

Download, install, and open the Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator.

Choose File > Load Existing Keyboard.

Select the keyboard you want to see.

Find the country or region name in the keyboard list that's followed by "(Apple)".

Follow the instructions provided with the app. You can print images of the keyboard, including what keys look like when holding modifiers like Shift, Option, or Fn.